# NoReverseMatch Error Django/Apache

Tags: python, html, django

I have an HTML page with a drop-down menu and linked submit button, to post the value of the selected option. The post works fine, and the code executed from the post, but I receive a 'NoReverseMatch' error at the 'HttpResponseRedirect' line in the view dedicated to processing the post data.

Here's snippets from the program:

In the app/urls.py file:

```
...
url(r'^classifications/(?<class_list>[\w-]+)/$', 'Event_Classification_View'),
url(r'^class_submit/$', 'Event_Classification_Submit_View'),
...
```

In the app/views.py file:

```
...
def Event_Classification_View(request, class_list):
    if class_list == 'NULL':
        return render_to_response('app/Classifications.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('app/Classifications.html', {'class_list': class_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def Event_Classification_Submit_View(request):
    ...
    classification_event_list = #list of items
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.Event_Classification_View', args=(classification_event_list,)))
...
```

What should happen is the user clicks a button on the Home page that takes them to `/localhost/app/classifications/NULL/`, which is accounted for in the first listed urls.py line. This loads the Event_Classification_View, and since `class_list == NULL` nothing is passed to the HTML file, and it (which contains the post and drop-down) is loaded. This works fine.

When the user selects an option in the drop-down and clicks the "Submit" button with it, this loads the url `/localhost/app/class_submit/`, which runs the `Event_Classification_Submit_View` method. After processing the post and running extra code, this should create the object `classification_event_list`, which is then returned to the `Event_Classification_View` method to be sent to the HTML for output. However, I'm receiving the NoReverseMatch error instead of the `Event_Classification_View` running again. The list is being generated, but for some reason the exception is thrown giving a value "Reverse for 'app.views.Event_Classification_View' with arguments '([list_items],)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Can anyone see what could be going wrong here? I have another of these "post" sections in the same program and it works fine. Thanks! (I'm running Django 1.4.22 and apache2 as well, on Python 2.7)

EDIT:
I think I've found the culprit of my issue: the "qualifier" for the URL item that gets passed to the View method as an argument, i.e. in my case the `[\w-]+`. I changed this to `\d+` and tried returning as an arg a string, and received the same error while a # or a '#' worked just fine (`\d+` is only for digits I believe). Is there a way to or "qualifier" to allow a Python list to be passed into the url for `class_list`?

Comment: Not related to you problem but why are you still using Django 1.4?

Comment: @S.M.Styvane The machine acting as the server is running Debian 7.9, and I've been told (as it's not my machine) that 1.4 is the highest it can run.